# how to configure a real ip on windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, static-ip, external-ip

we got an real -static , external- IP address for our router to be able to access network from outside.
i need to assign this IP to a a server running windows 2008 R2 to access sites hosted on it

Comment: In the same way that you'd set any other IP.  Can you clarify exactly what issue you're having?

Comment: i dont have any problem , i just want to assign this ip address to the server i dont know how to do that (i'm newbie in networking) very beginner :)

Comment: What type of edge router do you have?  You need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

As you said: The IP is for your router! If you don't put it on the router it cannot be routed (sounds logic).

From the router do DNAT to your server.

Comment: aha , Thank you sir , sorry i newbie in networking and administration (I'm a developer ^_^)

Comment: so could you tell me more info. :)

Comment: No. Where should I start? Do you know what a router is? Don't answer! This was rhetorical but should show you that this leads to hours and hours of discussion...